# Represent string data to tree

Tags: c#

I have the following data. This is a list of programs on my system.

```
[
  {
    "ID": 135,
    "CODIGO": 139,
    "NOME": "CADASTRO DE ANOS ATIVOS",
    "VISAO": "VANOSATIVOSCONTABIL",
    "CAMINHO": "Cadastros/Contabilidade/frm_AnosAtivosContabil.aspx, 139, ((VariaveisSistema)Session[VariaveisSistema]).UsuarioId.ToString().Trim(), frm_Visoes.aspx, , Nao"
  },
  {
    "ID": 59,
    "CODIGO": 35,
    "NOME": "CADASTRO DE CENTRO DE CUSTO",
    "VISAO": "VCENTROCUSTO",
    "CAMINHO": "Cadastros/Contabilidade/frm_CadastroCentroCusto.aspx, 035, ((VariaveisSistema)Session[VariaveisSistema]).UsuarioId.ToString().Trim(), frm_Visoes.aspx, , Nao"
  },
]
```

So, you can see that the program has a path like `Cadastros/Contabilidade`.

I need to conver the `Cadastros/Contabilidade` in a menu tree colapsable.

So the json data should look like this:

```
Cadastros 
    |
    | Contabilidade
         - frm_AnosAtivosContabil.aspx
         - frm_CadastroCentroCusto.aspx
         - frm_CadastroCFOP.aspx
         - ...

    | Globais
         - frm_AlteraFormacaoArvore.aspx
         - frm_AssociacaoCalendario.aspx
         - frm_AssociacaoItemTransferencia.aspx
         - ...
```

I am using C#. I managed to separate the programs along the way (group them). But I have not managed to separate them into menus.

The node structure is:

```
public class Node
{
    public IList<Programa> Programs { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public Node Parent { get; set; }
    public IList<Node> Childrens { get; set; }
}
```

Program structure:

```
public class Programa
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Codigo { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Visao { get; set; }        
    public IList<UsuarioPrograma> UsuariosPrograma { get; set; }
    public string Caminho { get; set; }
}
```

I can create the root node. But i dont kno how to proceed.

```
private void CreateNode(Programa programa)
{
    var paths = programa.Caminho.Split('/');

    // Verifica se já é o pai
    if (paths.Length == 1)
    {
        // Verifica se o nó já existe
        var node = Menu.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == paths[0]);

        if (node == null)
        {
            node = new Node();
            node.Name = paths[0];
            node.Programs = new List<Programa> { programa };

            Menu.Add(node);
        }

        else Menu.First(x => x.Name == paths[0]).Programs.Add(programa);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with your code segment(s) that demonstrate your best attempt to resolve this, and then explain at what point in that code you're not getting the results you want.

Comment: I need to fill a list of nodes (a tree) with the json. No matter wich framework i'm using. I'll render in a asp:Repeater component the tree.

Comment: Do you want to just ignore everything after the path (for example, in your snippet, ignore `139, ((VariaveisSistema)Session[VariaveisSistema]).UsuarioId.ToString().Trim(), frm_Visoes.aspx, , Nao`)? if you want to keep it, where should it appear in your tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@augusto-henrique bit tricky but managed to bring the json object however you expecting to serialize, have a look this code and see whether this works for your requirements,

first I created a class to serialize the JSON you have

```
  public class Page
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public int CODIGO { get; set; }
            public string NOME { get; set; }
            public string VISAO { get; set; }
            public string CAMINHO { get; set; }
        }
```

Then I am grouping the values and adding into dictionary objects as nested collection

```
var json1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Page>>
                        (File.ReadAllText(@"c:\temp\test1.json"));

            var root1 = json1.Select(x => x.CAMINHO)
                    .Select(x => x.Split(",")[0])
                    .Select(x => x.Split("/"))
                    .Select(x => new
                    {
                        level1 = x.First(),
                        level2 = x.Skip(1).First(),
                        level3 = x.Skip(2).First()
                    })
                    .GroupBy(x => new { x.level1, x.level2, x.level3 }, (key, grp) => new
                    {
                        Level1 = key.level1,
                        Level2 = key.level2,
                        Level3 = key.level3,
                        groups = grp
                    });
            var jsonObject = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (var level1 in root1)
            {
                if (!jsonObject.ContainsKey(level1.Level1))
                {
                    jsonObject.Add(level1.Level1, new Dictionary<string, object[]>());
                }
                if (!((Dictionary<string, object[]>)jsonObject[level1.Level1]).ContainsKey(level1.Level2))
                    ((Dictionary<string, object[]>)jsonObject[level1.Level1]).Add(level1.Level2, new[] { level1.Level3 });
                else
                {
                    var list = (((Dictionary<string, object[]>)jsonObject[level1.Level1])[level1.Level2]).ToList();
                    list.Add(level1.Level3);
                    ((Dictionary<string, object[]>)jsonObject[level1.Level1])[level1.Level2] = list.ToArray();
                }  

            }
            var jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObject);
```

the result of jsonText would look like, hope from this you can develop further., may require some refactoring,

[image: JSON Document]